# Sagepay form integeration

Tags: php, opayo

I am configuring Sage pay form integration on my site. All went good. i achieved every thing which is required i can do payments now on sage pay.

the response sage pay return is like this.

```
    Array
(
    [env] => test
    [vendorName] => Vendor name
    [integrationType] => form
    [basket] => Array
        (
            [items] => Array
                (
                )

        )

[decrypt] => Array
    (
        [VendorTxCode] => kingkebab-PAYMENT-1530730472-792775742
        [VPSTxId] => {45A5E0B8-DA1A-B3CE-424A-6E8BF2C8EA05}
        [Status] => OK
        [StatusDetail] => 0000 : The Authorisation was Successful.
        [TxAuthNo] => 18306833
        [AVSCV2] => SECURITY CODE MATCH ONLY
        [AddressResult] => NOTMATCHED
        [PostCodeResult] => NOTMATCHED
        [CV2Result] => MATCHED
        [GiftAid] => 0
        [3DSecureStatus] => NOTCHECKED
        [CardType] => VISA
        [Last4Digits] => 0006
        [Surcharge] => 3.50
        [DeclineCode] => 00
        [ExpiryDate] => 1221
        [Amount] => 59.60
        [BankAuthCode] => 999777
    )

[currency] => GBP
[isSuccess] => 1
[message] => OK
[res] => Array
    (
        [vpsTxId] => {45A5E0B8-DA1A-B3CE-424A-6E8BF2C8EA05}
        [txAuthNo] => 18306833
        [Surcharge] => 3.50
        [BankAuthCode] => 999777
        [DeclineCode] => 00
        [GiftAid] => 
        [avsCv2] => SECURITY CODE MATCH ONLY
        [addressResult] => NOTMATCHED
        [postCodeResult] => NOTMATCHED
        [cv2Result] => MATCHED
        [3DSecureStatus] => NOTCHECKED
        [CAVV] => 
        [cardType] => VISA
        [last4Digits] => 0006
        [expiryDate] => 1221
        [addressStatus] => 
        [payerStatus] => 
    )
```

)

But there is one thing where i just stuck. The thing i want is to send my custom field in encrypted data of sage pay and want to get it back when transaction done successfully and give me response and decrypt it. the field i want is like order no etc.

Can anyone please help me out on this.

Comment: You may be best keeping that in storage, matched up to the `VendorTxCode`.

Answer (score 0):

If the payload is alphanumeric characters and less than 200 in length, you could send it to Sage Pay in the vendordata field. This isn't included in the response to the transaction, but you could then make a supplementary call using the reporting API and pull it out that way....

Answer (score 0):

This is old, I know, but the issue is still one people may need to tackle.

You send the `VendorTxCode` with the encrypted form data, and (unlike the example given by OP here) you *do* get the `VendorTxCode` back in the final result. That ID will be unique and generated by the merchant site, and can be used to identify the original transaction in storage. So don't send the order ID, send the `VendorTxCode` used to look up the order ID when the user returns.

An alternative method, which is not entirely what was asked for, is to add additional data as query parameters to the `SuccessURL`. This will be encrypted on the way *to* the Sage Pay gateway, but won't be encrypted on the way back, so could be subject to manipulation. You would need to validate it against the session (rendering it a waste of time, when the value might as well be in the session to start with) or encrypt or sign it separately yourself, which could lead to some very long URLs.